# mx4 ubuntu edition turn on CallerID

Tags: ubuntu-touch, meizu-mx4

I just got my Ubuntu Edition of the Meizu MX4 and I noticed that there
is no option to turn on CallerID in the System Settings. How i can turn it on?

Comment: looks like the caller id can not be set from this post https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg14443.html